# Tail recursion : filter nested lists in scala

Tags: scala, nested-lists, tail-recursion

The following function filters (removes the `1`'s ) in a nested list:

```
def filter(list : List[Any], acc : List[Any] = Nil) : List[Any] = {
  list match {
    case Nil => acc
    case (l : List[_]) :: tail =>
      val nested = filter(l)

      if (nested.isEmpty) filter(tail, acc)
      else
        filter(tail, acc :+ nested)

    case 1 :: tail =>     filter(tail, acc)
    case other :: tail => filter(tail, acc :+ other)
  }
}
```

Input

`filter(List(1, 3, 4, List(1, 4 ,5), List(1)))`

Output

`res0: List[Any] = List(3, 4, List(4, 5))`

My question is: How can I make this tail recursive? My main problem is how to handle the nested lists: `val nested = filter(l, Nil)`

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because there's no way to make just one call to `filter` on a list that contains multiple sublists, out of which each one needs to be filtered.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, think you can use *Free monad* to solve this, available, for example, in Typelevel Cats lib.

```
"org.typelevel" %% "cats-free" % "1.0.1"
```

Idea behind is to move recursion which could not be converted to tail-recursion to another part of code, where this is feasible

So, if you want some understanding on how to solve such task you need to read  [this](http://blog.higher-order.com/assets/trampolines.pdf) paper by Runar Oli Bjarnason (and probably watch [this](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/3244-stackless-scala-free-monads) presentation). After that you can try to solve your problem with trampolines written by yourself (based on paper and video):

First lets re-write your filter in a way (this step is not necessary, I was just under impression of even/odd example from paper, below I show how to do the same based on your variant):

```
private def filterList(l: List[Any]): Option[Any] = {
  l.foldLeft(Option.empty[List[Any]]) {
    case (acc, next) if acc.isEmpty =>
      filter1(next).map(_ :: Nil)
    case (acc, next) =>
      acc.map(_ ++ filter1(next))
  }
}

private def filter1(a: Any): Option[Any] = a match {
  case 1 => Option.empty[Any]
  case l: List[Any] => filterList(l)
  case t => Some(t)
}

def filter(l: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
  filterList(l) match {
    case Some(l: List[Any]) => l
    case _ => Nil
  }
}
```

Now let's assume that `Trampoline` is already available (and it is available, see below) and rewrite this with trampolines:

```
def filterList(l: List[Any]): Trampoline[Option[Any]] = {
  l.foldLeft[Trampoline[Option[List[Any]]]](Done(Option.empty[List[Any]])) {
    case (acc, next) =>
      acc.flatMap {
        case None => filter1(next).map(_.map(_ :: Nil))
        case v =>
          filter1(next).map (r => v.map(_ ++ r))
      }
  }
}

def filter1(a: Any): Trampoline[Option[Any]] = a match {
  case 1 => Done(Option.empty[Any])
  case l: List[Any] => More(() => filterList(l))
  case t => Done(Some(t))
}

def filter(l: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
  filterList(l).runT match {
    case Some(l: List[Any]) => l
    case _ => Nil
  }
}
```

`Trampoline` implementation (based on paper and video)

```
sealed trait Trampoline[+A] {
  final def runT: A =
    this match {
      case Done(a) => a
      case More(k) => k().runT
      case t: FlatMap[Any, A] => t match {
        case Done(a) FlatMap f => f(a).runT
        case More(k) FlatMap f => k().flatMap(f).runT
        case FlatMap(xg: FlatMap[Any, A], f) =>
          xg.a.flatMap(a => xg.f(a)).runT
      }
    }

  def map[B](f: A => B): Trampoline[B] =
    flatMap(x => More(() => Done(f(x))))

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Trampoline[B]): Trampoline[B] = this match {
    case FlatMap(a, g: Any) => FlatMap(a, (x: Any) => g(x) flatMap f)
    case x => FlatMap(x, f)
  }
}

case class More[+A](k: () => Trampoline[A])
  extends Trampoline[A]

case class Done[+A](result: A)
  extends Trampoline[A]

case class FlatMap[A, B](a: Trampoline[A], f: A => Trampoline[B])
  extends Trampoline[B]
```

Now, with all these parts you can check that now you have working stack-less recursive implementation. I used such code for test:

```
def check(i: Int, output: Boolean) {
  val l = (1 to i).foldLeft(List[Any](1, 2, 3)) {
    case (l, _) =>
      List[Any](1, 2, 3, l, List(1))
  }

  val res = filter(l)
  if (output) {
    println(s"Depth: $i, result: " + res)
  }
}

check(3, true)
check(10000, false)
```

It fails on non-trampoline approach with `StackOverflowError` and completes successfully on modified one.

**Update with Cats**

I tried same approach with `cats-free` lib. It works perfectly as well:

```
import cats.free._
import cats.implicits._

def filterList(l: List[Any]): Trampoline[Option[Any]] = {
  l.foldLeft[Trampoline[Option[List[Any]]]](Trampoline.done(Option.empty[List[Any]])) {
    case (acc, next) =>
      acc.flatMap {
        case None => filter1(next).map(_.map(_ :: Nil))
        case v =>
          filter1(next).map (r => v.map(_ ++ r))
      }
  }.map(_.map(identity[Any]))
}

def filter1(a: Any): Trampoline[Option[Any]] = a match {
  case 1 => Trampoline.done(Option.empty[Any])
  case l: List[Any] => Trampoline.defer(filterList(l))
  case t => Trampoline.done(Some(t))
}

def filter(l: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
  filterList(l).run match {
    case Some(l: List[Any]) => l
    case _ => Nil
  }
}
```

**Using Cats Trampoline with original code**

I tried to do the same with your original code, here is the result:

```
import cats.free._
import cats.implicits._

private def filterInner(list : List[Any], acc : List[Any] = Nil) : Trampoline[List[Any]] = {
  list match {
    case Nil => Trampoline.done(acc)
    case (l : List[_]) :: tail =>
      Trampoline.defer(filterInner(l)).flatMap {
        case Nil => Trampoline.defer(filterInner(tail, acc))
        case nested => Trampoline.defer(filterInner(tail, acc :+ nested))
      }
    case 1 :: tail =>     Trampoline.defer(filterInner(tail, acc))
    case other :: tail => Trampoline.defer(filterInner(tail, acc :+ other))
  }
}
def filter(list : List[Any]): List[Any] = filterInner(list).run
```

Note, that every recursive call to `filterInner` is wrapped to `Trampoline.defer`, it is done to eliminate recursion. You can test it by removing wrapping in `case (l : List[_]) :: tail` part and run on my test example.

Comment: Big thanks for such a great answer! I will probably need a few days to fully understand every detail, but thanks for all the links and explanations!